# Python/Selenium Script displays empty screen - data; page

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chromium, raspberry-pi4

I'm trying to figure out why the following script is working when I launch it with pi user on my raspberry and not with root user.

Goal: It should open Chromium full screen, and log into the website.
With root user, it opens the web client and doesn't display anything. Screen is white, and it gives me a `data;` page then a `Privacy error` page.

```py
#!/home/pi/Documents/raspberry_screen_chrome_script/selenium/bin/python3
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

username_django = 'username'
password_django = 'password'

chrome_options = Options()

chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222");
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-fullscreen")
chrome_options.add_argument("--kiosk")

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver', options=chrome_options)
driver.get ("my_url")
driver.find_element_by_id('id_username').send_keys(username_django)
driver.find_element_by_id('password-input').send_keys(password_django)
driver.find_element_by_id('submit-login').click()
```

What I used:

```
selenium==3.141.0
webdriver-manager==3.4.2
Chromium 88.0.4324.187 Built on Raspbian , running on Raspbian 10
ChromeDriver 88.0.4324.187
```

Output when launching it with root user

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi/Documents/raspberry_screen_chrome_script# ./interface_login_local.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./interface_login_local.py", line 21, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_id('id_username').send_keys(username_django)
  File "/home/pi/Documents/raspberry_screen_chrome_script/selenium/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 360, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
  File "/home/pi/Documents/raspberry_screen_chrome_script/selenium/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "/home/pi/Documents/raspberry_screen_chrome_script/selenium/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/pi/Documents/raspberry_screen_chrome_script/selenium/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="id_username"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.187)
```

Edit (Added Gifs to explain behaviour):

Behaviour as Pi User

[image: Behaviour as Pi User]

Behaviour as Root User (the white block are coming when I try to right click)

[image: Behaviour as Root User]

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not share the actual URL you are opening with this code we can only guess what is the issue.
So, it can be:

1. You need to add a wait / delay before accessing the username element to let the page loaded and only then access the element.
2. The element locator is possibly wrong.
3. Element can be inside an iframe.

Comment: if the locators are not correct and if it is in iframe or it it needs wait/delay, then why the same code is working in pi user on his raspberry ? but not with the root user.?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just edited my question to add a gif with the behaviour. I tried with the url `https://www.google.com`, added 20 sec of `time.sleep()`, and commented out anything about finding element. I don't think that the issue is coming from the element locator, as explained It works perfectly fine when launching the program with pi user.

Comment: @cruisepandey The question was edited 2 minutes ago...

Comment: @Welyweloo this changes the question details drastically

Comment: yes but it was there `I launch it with pi user on my raspberry and not with root user.` when he posted for first time.